# How to load a nodelet into a manager from CPP

Tags: roscpp, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I using a set of nodelets that until now have been started from a lauch file, loading into the standard [nodelet manager](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nodelet/Tutorials/Running%20a%20nodelet) (`rosrun nodelet nodelet manager`). Now I would like one of those nodelets (a CPP node) to be able to load and unload nodelets in it's manager but can't get it to work.

Loading from the command line using the nodelet tool or via a launch file (which is the same tool) works. But if I try calling the load_nodelet service on the manager the nodelet seems to load, maybe processes a callback or two but then disappears again!

Looking at the source for the nodelet tool (`$(rospack find nodelet)/src/nodelet.cpp`) it seems that after calling the service on the manager it spins it's own ros loop and does some funky things with signal handlers and bonds.

- What is this process doing?
- If the nodelet is running as a thread in the
  manager why do we need this other
  process to keep the nodelet running?

Edit: These are answered by reading about bonds [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/9499/what-are-bond-topics-for/) and [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/bond). However I still want to know:

- How can I load a nodelet into the manager from a CPP node?

(I'm currently working around this with a fork and exec to rosrun nodelet, but that is not a good solution).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52462/how-to-load-a-nodelet-into-a-manager-from-cpp/) by [markpitchless](https://answers.ros.org/users/1668/markpitchless/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Jan.

I am also trying to do this. I can call the service in cpp code. The problem is I cannot add the parameters. Anyway, I can tell you how I did it.

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "tracker"); // Initialize ROS coms
ros::NodeHandle* n = (ros::NodeHandle*) new ros::NodeHandle("~"); //The node handle

ros::ServiceClient client = n->serviceClient<nodelet::NodeletLoad>("/nodelet_manager/load_nodelet"); //this is my service name

nodelet::NodeletLoad srv;
srv.request.name = "name1";
srv.request.type = "race_3d_object_tracking/race_3d_object_tracking_nodelet"; //this is my nodelet

//This is the part that does not work. But the rest does. Meaning I can call the service and it runs, but I cannot change the parameters
//srv.request.remap_source_args.push_back("name");
//srv.request.remap_target_args.push_back("new_name");                                                                                                  
//srv.request.my_argv.push_back("point_cloud_in:=/camera/depth_registered/points");


if (client.call(srv))
{   
    ROS_INFO("Service response ok");
}   
else
{   
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to call service");
}
```

If you can find how to insert params please tell me.

Regards

Miguel

---

Originally posted by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) with karma: 254 on 2013-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on 2013-06-26**:
Actually, I was reading around the ros answers forum and I found some other stuff. I asked a new question related to this one. Perhaps you can check it, is at http://answers.ros.org/question/66017/load-nodelet-service-as-an-library/